# Elements in a div collapsing too early

Tags: html, css

I'm having a problem enforcing 2 SVG menu elements in a div to stay side-by-side when a page is resized beneath a certain point.  Here's an example...

http://codepen.io/d3wannabe/pen/JYgjbZ

Please ignore the fact that clicking on the menus doesn't work properly - the issue is that they start off perfectly centered, but when you reduce the size of page past a certain point, 1 of the menus jumps beneath the other, despite the fact there's visibly plenty of room left on the page to allow both on the top line.

The basic structure I'm using is...

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: -10px;">
  <nav id="menu" class="menu">
    ...
  </nav>
  <nav id="menu2" class="menu">
    ...
  </nav>
</div>
```

Where the menu class is defined as follows...

```
.menu {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
    transform: translate(-100%, 0%);
}
```

But I see nothing in there that seems like it would account for this behaviour.  Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated, even if it's just a better method to troubleshoot this behaviour - thanks!

Comment: Why do you use position: absolute? .. There is other ways to center to images, so I wonder, is it the centering what you are after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a `width: 100%` on the container.

Instead of:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: -10px;">
```

Try this:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 50%; top: -10px; width: 100%;">
```

[**DEMO**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojKXWe)

Comment: thanks so much - so damn simple, but I'd wrongly assumed that the width would default to 100% if I hadn't specified it!

Comment: In many cases you would be right, but not with absolutely positioned elements. You need to specify a width/height or they will simply wrap content or default to zero w/h if there is no content.

Comment: @d3wannabe So you mean that the horizontal scrollbar is suppose to be there?